Jnative hook install showing import cannot be resolved
I installed Jnativehook by adding it groupid and artifact id directly to pom.xml in vscode. But when I am importing jnativehook it is not being recognized. I can see the jnativehook package in my maven dependencies. Am I missing something?
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.kwhat</groupId>      
      <artifactId>jnativehook</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  
  </dependencies>


vscode with jnative example and sharing package installed in maven in bottom left

I tried all possible answers overstackoverflow. Adding the dependencies over pom.xml is not working.

In the pom.xml file I have:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.kwhat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jnativehook</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Additional libs -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jnr</groupId>
    <artifactId>jnr-ffi</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.0</version>
</dependency>

The in my class file I have as imports:
import com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

As you can see in the image below, it worked for me.

So instead of trying to import from org.jnativehook, try importing from com.github.kwhat.jnativehook instead.
